# How to solve an equation vectorwise?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, solver

Is there any vectorwise equation solver in matlab?

For example if I have a vector `a = [1 8 27]` then solving `x.^3-a=0` will give us `[1 2 3]`

Thanks!

Comment: I've noticed that you haven't been giving enough attention to many of the suggested answers provided to your questions. Please consider reviewing them (possible upvoting and/or [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if they were helpful) to show that you care.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html):

```
>> x = fminsearch(  @(x) sum( ( x.^3 - a ).^2 ), [0 0 0] )

 x =
 1.0000    2.0000    3.0000
```

Comment: Don't see why `fsolve(  @(x) x.^3,a )` won't do it, but it doesn't and thus `fminsearch` seems to be the straightforward way to go for numeric solutions.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin it's `fsolve( @(x) x.^3 - a, [1 1 1] );` you need to solfe for `F(x)=0`.

Comment: I see, I am suprised to see that `fsolve` seems to give much better accuracy for this problem than the `fminsearch`. If you agree perhaps update the answer. (Perhaps it is just a different default setting, but still)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin for some reason, `fminsearch` performed better on my machine (less sensative to init point `x0`). I'll leave the answer as-is with `fsolve` as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/symbolic/solve.html) command.

The good news is that it is quite easy to use and rather powerfull.

Unfortunately you do need the symbolic toolbox to use this.

Here is an example:

```
syms a b c x
solve(a*x^2 + b*x + c == 0)
```

If you don't have the symbolic toolbox you wont be able to run this.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `arrayfun` and `fzero` to achieve this:

```
>> arrayfun(@(a) fzero(@(x) x^3-a,0), [1 8 27])
ans =
    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000
```